# Calling a function from stateflow

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I am trying to call a function (can be matlab function or a simlink function) from a stateflow in one subsystem, the function must be located in another subsystem as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVPf.jpg)

The first subsystem will have a stateflow which calls this function. It doesn't really matter if this function is a M-script, currently I do not know how to work around with matlab function (mscript) as it needs the arguments of the functions as inputs.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ml.functionname()`  would solve the issue, if passing the argument in a function be sure u have them defined in model explorer for respective Stateflow.